# Solr Json Support

Tags: solr, solrj

Solr provides way to query in JSON Format -

curl http://localhost:8983/solr/techproducts/query -d '
{
  "query" : "memory",
  "filter" : "inStock:true"
}'

Can I just pass this json as it is to SOLRJ Client. I need to intercept the request and pass it as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially, we can also set the parameter "json" and the query in SolrJ SolrQuery:

```
SolrQuery.add("json", "{json query here}")
```

Answer (score 0):

SolrJ client send queries as url parameters (`q=memory&fq=inStock:true`) and response type is `javabin` https://wiki.apache.org/solr/javabin

You can use [apache http client](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/index.html) and set your `JSON` query and fire request to Solr.

Comment: Thanks for the response, this is an options but since solr provides solr clients (http/cloud) I was thinking it will make sense if I can leverage that and just pass the query.